# wso2 ei 7.0.1 micro: Can not add oracle jdbc driver

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I did put ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar file into $IE_HOME/micro-integrator/lib path.

When did restart wso ei micro with command:
sudo service wso2mi restart

When did put my car file into dir:
$IE_HOME/micro-integrator/lib/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps

After restarting i see next error logs:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: 
            oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver cannot be found by jdbc-pool_7.0.81.wso2v2

    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.description.config.RDBMSConfig.<init>(RDBMSConfig.java:39)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.description.config.ConfigFactory.getRDBMSConfig(ConfigFactory.java:91)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.description.config.ConfigFactory.createConfig(ConfigFactory.java:59)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DataServiceFactory.createDataService(DataServiceFactory.java:159)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.createDBService(DBDeployer.java:806)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.processService(DBDeployer.java:1164)
    at org.wso2.micro.integrator.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.deploy(DBDeployer.java:196)
    ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: 
            oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver cannot be found by jdbc-pool_7.0.81.wso2v2
```

Help me!

Configuration:

```
<data name="OracleMXDataService" transports="http https">

    <!--
    <config id="OracleMX">
        <property name="carbon_datasource_name">OracleMX</property>
    </config>
    -->

    <config id="OracleMX">
        <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.driver">
            oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.protocol">
            jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.32.170:1521:PLAT19</property>
        <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.user">
            smpmx</property>
        <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.password">
            smpmx</property>
        <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.minpoolsize">1</property>
        <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.maxpoolsize">10</property>
        <property name="org.wso2.ws.dataservice.validation_query"></property>
    </config>
...
</data>
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration that uses OracleDriver ?

Comment: I did add configuration in question

Comment: Did you stop the server and restart?